# EFI vs VTec Engine Types

Tags: honda, vtec

Could you please let me know which engine is good on fuel (EFI vs VTec) and also what is good for performance ?

Main differences and Advantages ?

Comment: is the EFI (Electronic fuel injection) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare EFI with V-TEC both are totally different technologies doing totally different things.

EFI means and I am assuming Electronic Fuel Injection. As the name suggests , it helps in injecting fuel to the cylinder through electronically controlled injectors without the use of carburetors. This massively helps fuel efficiency over the carb version of the engine.

Vtec on the other hand is Honda's way of implementing Variable Valve timing(almost) , it basically uses two camshaft profiles and an actuator to determine which type of valve life and duration change is necessary for which particular moment. So meaning it gives the engine two camshafts, below a set RPM say 4500 you will have a economy mode with normal fuel saving everyday camshaft, above that set RPM the performance camshaft profile will kick in giving you more power to perform overtaking and such.

So as you see there is No way these two totally different technologies can be compared to determine fuel efficiency or anything for that matter.

Comment: I wouldn't say that EFI massively helps fuel efficiency. After all, the air/fuel ratios are similar. Yes, it may provide fuel cut-off at deceleration, but that's a minor effect. The reason for using EFI is lower emissions obtained by closed-loop control of the process.

Comment: @juhist Unfortunately I beg to differ , We have two models of the same motorcycle one with FI and other is carb, the FI version saves 6km/l more than the carb.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your abbreviations, when you say EFI you mean [Electronic Fuel Injection](http://www.aa1car.com/library/fuel_injection_basics.htm)?  I would say pretty much every car made in that last 25 years uses EFI, as opposed to the older technology of carburettors.  This does provide better fuel economy.

[Honda's VTEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTEC) also helps improve economy:

> VTEC (Variable Valve Timing and Lift Electronic Control) is a system developed by Honda to improve the volumetric efficiency of a four-stroke internal combustion engine (i.e. improved economy).

There's not really anything to compare and contrast, as they are complimentary technologies; it's not like it's an either / or situation.  In fact, I'm pretty sure that every car that has VTEC also uses EFI.